# How to do map inversion with Guava with non-unique values?

Tags: java, collections, guava

How can we do that with Guava? Notice the presence of `List<K>` in the return type since many keys can map to the same value in any normal map.

```
public static <K, V> Map<V, List<K>> inverse(Map<K, V> map){
    Map<V, List<K>> result = new LinkedHashMap<V, List<K>>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if(!result.containsKey(entry.getValue())){
            result.put(entry.getValue(), new ArrayList<K>());                
        }
        result.get(entry.getValue()).add(entry.getKey());
    }        
    return result;        
}
```

`BiMap` seems to insist on the unicity of the values, but I don't have this luxury.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Map<K, V> map = ...;
ListMultimap<V, K> inverse = Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(map), 
    ArrayListMultimap.<V,K>create());
```

Do note that pretty much any time you write `Map<K, List<V>>` or `Map<K, Set<V>>` or some such, a `ListMultimap<K, V>` or `SetMultimap<K, V>` is what you really want.

Comment: But is is annoying to be forced to convert to Multimap. And considering the effort they put on performances, it may be improved in the future, with something more sexy.

Comment: @lacroix1547 Huh? `Multimaps.forMap()` returns a _view_ of the given map. It does almost no work... it just calls a constructor and assigns the map to a field. That's it. Consider it an adapter that allows you to use a map with methods like `invertFrom()` that expect a `Multimap`.

Comment: Yeah ok I didnt opened forMap. I guess was right :) they put efforts on performances.

Answer (score 7):

Use a Multimap instead, pick one that uses a list, like
[ArrayListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html), that will allow dupes.

Also you don't have to write your own invert method, there's one provided in [com.google.common.collect.Multimaps](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#invertFrom%28com.google.common.collect.Multimap,%20M%29).

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles here now (well within Java's `Stream` era), here are two single-expression `Stream`-based solutions:

1) Immutable version based on [`ImmutableListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html) + [`toImmutableListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableListMultimap.html#toImmutableListMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) collector

```
ImmutableListMultimap<V, K> output = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(ImmutableListMultimap.toImmutableListMultimap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey));
```

2) Mutable version based on [`ArrayListMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) + [`Multimaps.toMultimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#toMultimap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) collector

```
ListMultimap<V, K> output = inputMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Multimaps.toMultimap(Map.Entry::getValue, Map.Entry::getKey, ArrayListMultimap::create));
```