# Guava: construct a Multimap by inverting a Map

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, guava, multimap

why does Guava doesn't have the following factory call to create a MultiMap from a normal Map?

```
public static <K,V> MultiMap<K,V> invertMap(Map<V,K> map);
```

I have program-names mapped to an integer of how often they were called. I'd like to invert this, so that i can ultimately construct a TreeMap, sorted by call-count, which then are the keys leading to one or multiple program-names.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678601/how-to-do-map-inversion-with-guava-with-non-unique-values

Comment: Regarding duplicate: This Question is better stated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
public static <K,V> Multimap<K,V> invertMap(Map<V,K> map) {
    return Multimaps.invertFrom(Multimaps.forMap(map), ArrayListMultimap.create());
}
```

Doesn't seem like this requires a dedicated function.  You can even get back to a `TreeMap` pretty easily:

```
Map<String, Integer> programCounts;
TreeMap<Integer, Collection<String>> map = 
    new TreeMap<>(
        Multimaps.invertFrom(
           Multimaps.forMap(programCounts),
           ArrayListMultimap.create()
        ).asMap()
    );
```

Comment: But doesn't this create two maps, so it's a bit slower?

Comment: @Fabian: It creates a Multimap and a TreeMap.  It doesn't create two Multimaps; `forMap` returns a *view* of the map.

Comment: To put it another way: Multimaps.forMap just creates a wrapper around programCounts, and an inexpensive one at that.  It's a constant-time, constant-memory operation.