# Jollyday Regions of Holiday

Tags: collections, groovy

I'm using [jollyday](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/data/de.html) for checking the holidays for showing them in a calendar.

With that i'm getting the Holidays as a Set, by calling the Method with the year and the regionCode:

```
HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayCalendar.GERMANY);
Set<Holiday> holidays =m.getHolidays(year, regionCode)
```

Perhaps I have to do this multiple times for different regionCodes, but all comes in one Set. 
After I have all the holidays i want to make a Map with Informations to this Holiday:

```
Map getCalendarProperties(Holiday holiday) {
    HolidayManager m = HolidayManager.getInstance(HolidayCalendar.GERMANY);

    Map a = [:]
    a.tooltip = "<div class='row'>" +
            "<div class='col-xs-6'><b>${holiday.description}</b></div>" +
            "<div class='col-xs-6'>    </div>" +
            "</div>"  
    a.date = holiday?.date.toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd"));
    return a
}
```

I would like to write in the tooltip in which regions of Germany this Holiday is available.

I could check the Date for every Region, but this is to much for that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't really tell what is your problem or question here...

Comment: My question is how do i get a list of Regions where a Holiday is available?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the API of jollyday does not offer the view you want, and it's not using a proper [multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157080/guava-construct-a-multimap-by-inverting-a-map) which could do this by itself, you have to just construct it. Do something like this (untested code, my Groovy is rusty):

```
regionsForHolidays = [:]
regions.each{ region -> 
    holidays = m.getHolidays(year, region)
    holidays.each{ holiday ->
        set = regionsForHolidays[holiday]
        if(set==null){
            set = []
            regionsForHolidays[holiday] = set
        }
        set.add(region)
    }
}
```

Then you can query `regionsForHolidays[holiday]` and get a set of regions.