# What is the best Data Structure to create inverted index in Java?

Tags: java, information-retrieval, indexer

I have filtered Token Stream with me.
Now I need to create a Indexer for it.
I am aware that HashMap get/put operations are O(1). So I will be using that for sure.
The problem in deciding the best Data Structure keeping in mind the search queries on that indexer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do map inversion with Guava with non-unique values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678601/how-to-do-map-inversion-with-guava-with-non-unique-values)

Answer (score 3):

The most suitable data-structure for an inverted list is the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure. The problem with a hashmap is that it will allow only exact matches. The advantage of the trie data structure is that it allows for prefix matches, e.g. bring matches the prefix of bringing. A robust and efficient trie implementation in Java is the Apache commons [PatriciaTrie](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html).