# Java invert a map

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need to invert an original map. which type is `<Integer, String>`, like `{1 = A, 2 = A, 3 = B....}`. I want to create a new map which is `String` to `ArrayList` because if `1 = A`, and `2 = A`, than I want to have something like this: `A = [1， 2]`.

So how can I do that?

Comment: iterate over the existing map?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678601/how-to-do-map-inversion-with-guava-with-non-unique-values

Comment: Yeah I think I need to iterate one time and get key or values at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> original = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> inverted = new HashMap<>();

original.put(1, "A");
original.put(2, "B");
original.put(3, "C");
original.put(4, "A");

for (Integer key: original.keySet()) {
    String newKey = original.get(key);

    inverted.computeIfAbsent(newKey, k -> new ArrayList<>());
    inverted.get(newKey).add(key);

}
System.out.println(original);
System.out.println(inverted);
```

So, let's say `HashMap<Integer, String> original` is `{1=A, 2=B, 3=C, 4=A}`, then you will get `{A=[1, 4], B=[2], C=[3]}`.

**EDIT: If you want a more generic version, as @Mr.Polywhirl has suggested, you can use:**

```
public static final <T, U> Map<U, List<T>> invertMap(Map<T, U> map) {
    HashMap<U, List<T>> invertedMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (T key : map.keySet()) {
        U newKey = map.get(key);

        invertedMap.computeIfAbsent(newKey, k -> new ArrayList<>());
        invertedMap.get(newKey).add(key);

    }

    return invertedMap;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this (as opposed to the original version you posted) is that this requires 2 hash lookups per index.  If your hash is trivial like in the example, no biggie.  If you have several hundred items in it, you ought to do it the other way for the speedup-  there shouldn't be more than 1 get here (computeIfAbsent has to do a get to see if the item exists).

Comment: @GabeSechan, feel free to edit my answer to make this code more efficient. I do not have a great knowledge of Java.

Comment: Here's a generic version of the code above. Feel free to add it to your response. http://pastebin.com/yTExx5Fi

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, I have just done it, thank you so much, this is pretty useful since it is generic.

Comment: @GabeSechan `Map.computeIfAbsent` returns the value, whether existing or newly computed, so one can simply write: `invertedMap.computeIfAbsent(newKey, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(key)`.

Comment: @StuartMarks Ah, didn't know that.  In that case its a good solution, just remove the second get.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do it using Java 8's `stream` API, below is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, "A");
    map.put(2, "A");
    map.put(3, "B");

    Map<String, List<Integer>> invertedMap = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue, 
            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(invertedMap);

}
```

Comment: I really do not understand why people prefer using a streams approach for a problem like this. It seems to be unintuitive non-self documenting code. How is this better than the traditional looping example?

Comment: I'm not going to downvote because it isn't wrong, but I'd bounce this on a codereview.  Way too hard to figure out what the code is doing and if you're requirements change there's no way to alter it in place, you'd have to completely rewrite it.

Comment: General consesnsus here is, if Java already provides libraries/APIs for something, I would rather use that than writing my own boilerplate code (which won't be as efficient as Java's native APIs anyway).