# What is the best way to have a 1 is to N bi-directional Hashmap like structure in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have two entities, `Person` and `Age`. While the values of `Person` are unique, `Age` can be be same for multiple `Person`.

If I wanted to only lookup `Age` of a `Person`, I would have used a `HashMap`. But I also want to retrieve a list of `Person` of a particular `Age`. The solution I can think of is having another `HashMap<String, List<Long>>` for the reverse lookup. Is there a data structure or a map like interface with O(1) lookup in both the directions that does the job of two `HashMap`'s in one?
Please note that I used `Person` and `Age` as a trivial example, and that the real examples are not something stored in a database, but fetched from a service, so I have to handle them as I get.

**Update:**

I think Guavas [MultiMap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/11.0.2/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) can solve this issue. Because in my case both the key and value are `String`, so it will work. Just seems a little unclean though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bidirectional Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783020/bidirectional-map)

Comment: This is not a "reverse" it's an additional key (it's not just `String->Person` and `Person->String`, you have an additional `Integer->List<Person>`). I believe that warrants an additional map/multimap, although it could reuse the same `Person` objects in value lists.

Comment: @ernest-kiwele yes I guess it is not exactly reverse. But I want to do two types of queries, `Person`->`Age` and `Age`->`List<Person>`. I just wanted to know if there's one interface that gives both functionalities, because otherwise I need to maintain two HashMaps and make sure when I add a new `Person`, I also correctly add it to the `List<Person>` for that `Age`.

Comment: @DhireshJain perhaps take a look at this example using Guava: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3678660/6391367. It allows you to create a `ListMultimap` with a `value => key` mapping from a `Map`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how complex your requirement is - I have had a similar situation in the past but my situation was a bit more complex and I had 4 or 5 fields that I wanted to be able to look up on, so what I ended up doing was using an in-memory database (I used H2 but there are a few). I then indexed all the fields that I wanted to be able to look up by. Because it's in-memory, you get very fast speeds and if you use JPA etc the code is still pretty clean. Clearly this is more complicated that just using a HashMap but will scale better if your requirements get more complex.